# @import in CSS not recognised in Github HTML Preview?

Tags: html, css, github

I'm new to github and have uploaded a number of .html, .css and .js files.

I've tried using http://htmlpreview.github.com/? to preview my pages as they would appear with styles but am having an issue with @import in some of my stylesheets.

If I remove the @import and link all stylesheets individually then it all works fine, it's the @import causing the problem (I'm guessing because the Github Preview URL queries the page I'm viewing so everything has to be relative to that page?).

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way I can keep the @import as removing it is going to mean changes in literally hundreds of pages?

Example code from index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
```

Then jquery.ui.all.css contains a couple of imported style sheets using the following code:

```
@import url("jquery.ui.base.css");
```

Then jquery.ui.base.css contains more @import rules as below:

```
@import url("jquery.ui.accordion.css");
@import url("jquery.ui.autocomplete.css");
@import url("jquery.ui.button.css");
```

Cheers,

Jon

Comment: Provide examples of what your import-rules look like, please.

Comment: done, hope that helps!